# Two "forms" in one <form> clash their required attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

**The issue**:
I have a single page with two email forms (one `<form>`, two divs inside this which look like forms to the user). When you submit either form, the C# behind looks at the values of the form and sends them in an email. This works well, and now I want a little validation, but I can't add `required` attributes to the `inputs` as the code doesn't know it's two separate "forms" and needs to handle the `required` attributes separately for each one.

I understand why this issue occurs, but I want to know if there's a way to tell the page to handle the `required` attributes in groups.

**What I've tried**: Both "forms" are handled by the code behind, and so need to be run server-side, so separate `<form>` elements wouldn't work. I have tried nesting the "forms" as `<form>` elements inside the server-side `<form>`, which separates the `required` attributes as desired, but seemingly breaks a number of things and I've read this is generally bad practice anyway.

**What I'm not asking**: To validate the form in the code behind.

**Edit**:
David's answer works great to validate groups of textboxes, which is what I needed.

To additionally validate a checkbox, I used javascript. `onclientclick` we can check if the `checkbox` is checked AND validate using `Page_ClientValidate('validationgroup')` and then return true, else return false. `onclick` is only fired when `onclientclick` returns true.

Comment: why can't you try javascript validations ?

Comment: I can, but this is about making the code is simple and easy to read as possible, and so I'm asking for all alternatives, and why overcomplicate if we could simply use the `required` attribute? Judging by the answers so far, this isn't possible, which is a shame.

Comment: There are lot of restrictions while doing with asp.net validation controls. Since the a perfect web app supposed to execute in almost all popular browsers, you need to face more challenges to deliver a stable UI for different browsers. jQuery can do things easily and the code is also readable. I believe from VS 2010 onwards they are integrated jquery and promoting users to introduce javascripts in to the project. I am pretty sure that you can achieve using jquery easily and code is more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use one form with two submit buttons. Use `validationgroup` to distinguish

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: This works, but having the extra `<span>` for each error creates an extra line after each input, so I'll have to use javascript on top. Or is there a way to make it `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`? Also, have to use `customvalidator` for `checkbox`es.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, you have complete control over the validation controls so just change them

Comment: Nevermind, `display="Dynamic"` solves the visibility issue. While it's still not as nice as the browser highlighting when using the `required` attribute, this is the best alternative it seems.

Comment: I was answering the question, if you want browser highlighting ask about it!

Comment: Using `causesvalidation` and `onclientclick` on the `<asp:button>` causes issues which, upon researching, many others experience too with no quick fix.

Comment: They don't for me, instead of being vague and ungrateful why not be clearer on what you are trying to achieve. You ask for some way to " to handle the required attributes in groups." I said use a validation group. Why are you moaning about these two attributes, I never mentyione dthem

Comment: Ungrateful? Why? Because I haven't immediately voted your answer up or as correct? Be patient.

Comment: No, because you didn't thank anyone for their time. What specific issue are you having using validation groups?

Comment: Everything is currently working apart from validating a `<asp:checkbox>`. `<asp:requiredfieldvalidator>` doesn't work with checkboxes, and using both the requiredfieldvalidator and a `<asp:customvalidator>` doesn't work either (if I use just one or the other, they work, but with both, the checkbox doesn't validate). So I have tried using javascript to validate the checkbox, but `onclick` will always be triggered no matter what happens in the javascript function called by `onclientclick`.

Comment: Ok, Ill add another answer for that. Watch this space

Comment: Thanks for the help and the quick responses.

Answer (score 1):

if you write your own validation function for each submit button it should be possible

```
<input type='submit' onclick='return validateFirstButton()'/>
```

Comment: Sure, but I want to find out if there's a way to group required elements because for a single form using the `required` attribute on the necessary inputs is enough, but for two forms we have to use alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

To validate checkboxes follow the instructions here:

http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/07/19/How-to-add-a-required-validator-to-a-CheckBoxList.aspx

Because this derives from `BaseValidator` you will be able to use groups. Hope this helps

Comment: I found a way to do it through javascript. `onclientclick` we can check if the `checkbox` is checked AND validate using `Page_ClientValidate('validationgroup')` and then return true, else return false. `onclick` is only fired when `onclientclick` returns true. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out, though if you follow the link it also generates javascript and follows the .net pattern. But if it works then it works!